# Remove an object from the array of object based on the key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object,

```
arrayOfObj = [{All: true}, {Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}]
```

I need to remove an object based on the key.
For example, remove an object from the array where the key has `All`.

The answer should be:

```
arrayOfObj = [{Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}]
```

I need to do this only with `es6` syntax like filter or find

what i have tried is:

```
const o = Object.keys(obj);
      this.categoriesSelected = this.categoriesSelected.filter(r => r.o !== o);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use filter and look if the Object.keys include the unwanted key

```js
let arrayOfObj = [{All: true}, {Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}]
let unwantedKey = 'All';
let res = arrayOfObj.filter(e => ! Object.keys(e).includes(unwantedKey));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I tried your code and got an error property includes does not exist on type string

Comment: Then you didn’t try above code, or your array is different from what you’ve shown. @karty

Comment: only thing that i change is const key = Object.keys(obj); i even tried key[0]

Comment: Why are you setting it to an array then? @karty

Comment: see let unwantedKey = key[0];

Comment: Ahh. You're doing Object.keys(arrayOfObj) ? So just do a console.log(key[0]); and you will see your error yourself. Hint Object.keys is for objects, not for arrays... @karty

Comment: I am using this in angular. so this is typescript error.

Comment: No it’s not @karty

Answer (score 3):

If your array doesn't have duplicated objects then you can do it in an elegant way using [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const array = [{All: true}, {Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}];
const [All, ...rest] = array;
console.log(rest) // [{Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}]
```

More generic way is to use `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```js
const array = [{All: true}, {All: true}, {Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}];
const filterBy = (array, key) => array.filter(el => !el[key])
const result = filterBy(array, 'All');
console.log(result) // [{Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}]
```

Comment: Amazing...simple and sober

Comment: That will not work. What is happen if you have two object which has `All` property ? Answer: It will remove only first one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and the '[in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)' operator:

```
let arrayOfObj = [{All: true}, {Sports: true}, {Entertainment: true}]
let key= 'All';
let res = arrayOfObj.filter(o => !(key in o));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let arrayOfObj = [{ All: true }, { Sports: true }, { Entertainment: true }];

function removeProperty(arr, key) {
    return arr.filter((obj) => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)[0] != key);        
}

console.log(removeProperty(arrayOfObj, 'All'));
```